# Как определить компилятор

Tags: c++

С помощью каких макросов можно определить компилятор?

```
// clang++
#ifdef(???)
  #define CLANG_COMPILER
#endif

// MSVC
#ifdef(???)
  #define MS_COMPILER
#endif

// g++
#ifdef(???)
  #define GCC_COMPILER
#endif
```

Чтобы работал код наподобие такого

```
#if defined (CLANG_COMPILER)
  // clang++
#elif defined (MS_COMPILER)
  // MSVC
#elif defined (GCC_COMPILER)
  // g++
#else
  #error not supported 
#endif
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

где то так:

```
#if defined(__clang__)
  //clang
  #define CLANG_COMPILER
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__)
  //gcc https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html
  #define GCC_COMPILER
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
  //vs
  #define MS_COMPILER
#else
  #error "I don't know your compiler"
#endif
```

Но лучше писать код так, что бы это не было нужно.